# Why does tkinter PanedWindow.sash_place not work in bind_class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to customize the way the sash on a tkinter PanedWindow looked based on if the user is clicking on it, so I cam up with this.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class PanedTest(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(master)
        
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        
        self.style.configure('TPanedwindow', background='black')
        self.style.configure('Clicked.TPanedwindow', background='blue')
        self.style.configure('Sash', sashthickness = 8)
        
        self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<Button-1>', lambda e : e.widget.configure(style = 'Clicked.TPanedwindow'))
        self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>', lambda e : e.widget.sash_place(0, e.x, e.y))
        self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e : e.widget.configure(style = 'TPanedwindow'))
        
        self.paned1 = ttk.PanedWindow()
        self.paned1.pack()
        
        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.paned1, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned1.add(self.frame1)
        
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.paned1, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned1.add(self.frame2)
        
        
        self.paned2 = ttk.PanedWindow(orient = 'horizontal')
        self.paned2.pack()
        
        self.frame3 = ttk.Frame(self.paned2, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned2.add(self.frame3)
        
        self.frame4 = ttk.Frame(self.paned2, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned2.add(self.frame4)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PanedTest()
    app.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "paned_test.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>', lambda e : e.widget.sash_place(0, e.x, e.y))        
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4490, in sash_place
    return self.sash("place", index, x, y)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4464, in sash
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'sash') + args)) or ()
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!panedwindow2 sashpos index ?newpos?"
```

So after a lot of testing, I managed to get it to work with this

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class PanedTest(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(master)
        
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        
        self.style.configure('TPanedwindow', background='black')
        self.style.configure('Clicked.TPanedwindow', background='blue')
        self.style.configure('Sash', sashthickness = 8)
        
        self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<Button-1>', lambda e : e.widget.configure(style = 'Clicked.TPanedwindow'))
        self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>', lambda e : e.widget.sash(0, (e.x if str(e.widget.cget('orient')) == 'horizontal' else e.y)))
        self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e : e.widget.configure(style = 'TPanedwindow'))
        
        self.paned1 = ttk.PanedWindow()
        self.paned1.pack()
        
        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.paned1, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned1.add(self.frame1)
        
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.paned1, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned1.add(self.frame2)
        
        
        self.paned2 = ttk.PanedWindow(orient = 'horizontal')
        self.paned2.pack()
        
        self.frame3 = ttk.Frame(self.paned2, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned2.add(self.frame3)
        
        self.frame4 = ttk.Frame(self.paned2, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.paned2.add(self.frame4)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PanedTest()
    app.mainloop()
```

I can now drag the paned windows, but it does also give this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "paned_test.py", line 48, in <lambda>
    self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>', lambda e : e.widget.sash(0, (e.x if str(e.widget.cget('orient')) == 'horizontal' else e.y)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4463, in sash
    return self._getints(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1467, in _getints
    return tuple(map(self.tk.getint, self.tk.splitlist(string)))
TypeError: splitlist() argument must be str, bytes or bytearray, not int
```

Here's the difference between the two scripts

```py
self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>', lambda e : e.widget.sash_place(0, e.x, e.y))
```

vs

```py
self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>', lambda e : e.widget.sash(0, (e.x if str(e.widget.cget('orient')) == 'horizontal' else e.y)))
```

Why does only the second one work, and not the function that is specifically for what I am trying to do?

oh, and converting `e.widget.cget('orient')` to str is just because the result is a `<class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug on `tkinter`.  For your first code that uses `e.widget.sash_place(0, e.x, e.y)`, it just internally calls `self.sash('place', index, x, y)` which raises the invalid number of arguments error because `.sash()` expects two arguments, `index` and `pos`, only (i.e. how you use `.sash()` in your second code block.

However inside `.sash()` it calls `self._getints()` on the result of `self.tk.call(...)` which is an integer, but `self._getints()` expects a string. That is what the second error means.

To avoid the second error, you can use `e.widget.tk.call()` directly instead of `.sash()`:

```py
self.bind_class('TPanedwindow', '<B1-Motion>',
                lambda e: e.widget.tk.call(e.widget, "sash", 0, (e.x if str(e.widget["orient"]) == "horizontal" else e.y)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and a script that runs without errors.